# Regex replacing specific value within FIX message

Tags: regex, notepad++, fix-protocol

For any fixed message I wanted to use regex in notepad++ to replace particular values.

Given an example like below (where the | is the SOH character)

> 8=FIXT1.1|9=709|35=y|34=53|49=DUMMYBROKER|56=<client_ID>|52=20210211- 12:12:37.358847|55=AUD/CAD|55=AUD/CHF|55=AUD/JPY|55=AUD/NZD|55=AUD/USD|55= CAD/CHF|55=CAD/JPY|55=CHF/JPY|55=EUR/AUD|55=EUR/CAD|55=EUR/CHF

i came up with the regex

> [^\x{01}]*\49=[^\x{01}]*

In order to get

> 49=DUMMYBROKER

I.e get a value inbetween the SOH character, and starts with 49=

(Whether the selected result includes or excluded the SOH is optional, same with whether it just selects the value or with the 49= too)

For my particular example above my regex seems to work, however I'm not too experienced in regex and unsure about edge cases (such as if the message has similar values within another tag or something) or whether it is the cleanest

Could someone help to review ?

Comment: The very last field in a FIX message (of the form "`10=...|`") specifies a checksum value. If you change the value of any field in the message, you should also update the checksum field. Also, a field may repeat multiple times inside a repeating group.

Comment: You tagged it "quickfix", but I cannot see how this is relevant to QuickFIX.  QF has much easier ways of manipulating FIX data.

Comment: @Ciaran McHale, would you happen to have an example of such example where multiple fields are used?

Comment: @CaptainObv a Google search for "fix protocol repeating group example" yielded the following result that provides an example: https://ref.onixs.biz/fix-repeating-group.html

Comment: Moreover, tag 9 contains the body length which might change, depending on what you replace. And last not least, even the SOH character could appear in a data field. But I don't know if the resulting message still needs to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\x{01})49=[^\x{01}]+`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find Next</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\x{01})     # positive lookbehind, make sure we have SOH before
49=             # literally
[^\x{01}]+      # 1 or more any character that is not SOH
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use:

```
\b49=[^|]+
```

This should match only the portion starting with exactly `49`, followed by `=` and some right hand side value.

### Demo

Comment: Interesting. What is the difference between this and what i used? Largely the \b

Comment: `\b` is a word boundary.  It means ensure that `49` is not preceded by any other word character.